# CSS transition lost when array changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a simple react app that shifts and unshifts an array of letters. The transition animation occurs when a user hits `next` and `back` button. Functionally, the array is properly changed, but the transition only works for `next`. I have a hunch that this may be an issue more basic than React, but I did make sure that the key is unique to prevent redraw.

```
// this is the issue.
clickLeftRightHandler = () => {

    const { list } = this.state;
    // Does using slice or shifting the array cause a new redraw? Is it 
the CSS?
    const newList = [list[list.length-1], ...list.slice(0, -1)];

    this.setState({list : newList});

}
```

Code Link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7nsrjg

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason the animation wasn't working properly was due to the **key** being supplied to the Alphabet Component. The solution adds an index state that makes sure the shifted key receives a new key that's different from the cycled key.

It should also be noted that, @yuvi's updated example also implicitly fixes the issue with a new string that'll be passed to the key causing it to be uniquely set.

See updated [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-esqvtw)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `unshift` method:

```
clickLeftRightHandler = () => {

    const { list } = this.state;
    const newList = list.slice(0, -1);

    newList.unshift(list[list.length-1]);   // <-- right here 
    this.setState({list : newList});
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8m1bir?file=index.js)

**edit**

I honsetly don't know why it works, but it seems like if the string is a bit longer, the animation works as you want it to, so this works:

```
newList.unshift(list[list.length-1]+' ');
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vvprck?file=index.js). I don't know why's that happening, truly.

Comment: @bigbitecode note that I accidentally wrote `list.length-1` instead of `list[list.length-1]` at first so refresh the fork before testing it.

Comment: hmm, I just tried your new example, but it seems to be essentially resulting in a functionally similar way as my prev code. However, I'm not seeing the unshift help the animation transition smoothly like the `next` button.

Comment: @bigbitecode well, the animation works for me, though it throws the first part to the ending, which maybe isn't the way you want the animation to work? do you want it to drift from the right side?

Comment: Hey Yuvi, after your comment, I tried to change/fork from my code and use the example you've provided, but i'm still seeing the letters immediately shift to the location they are to be at while the last letter drifts to the right. The last letter isn't too much of a concern for me, but it's the immediate shift of the letters that concerns me.

For what it's worth, the line you have the comment `// <-- right here` if you change it to: `newList.unshift(list.length-1);` the animation is correct, but the values are not.

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fi6u4i?file=index.js

Comment: @bigbitecode that is so weird. I tried replacing the value manually (i.e. `newList.unshift("foo")`) and it seems that it works well with numbers, but not with strings. I'm very confused about this

Comment: @bigbitecode I'd say it has to to with the css animation and not with react but I'm not entirely sure why it would read strings different than numbers

Comment: Yea, I came to a similar hunch as well. Really appreciate your insights, yuvi.

Comment: I tried playing with it some more but I really gotta leave it for now. My next step if I were you would be to google about css animations working only in one direction, or something like that, maybe you'll find some answers.

Comment: @bigbitecode I solved it (see edit), but I don't feel good about it

Comment: Yea, the root of the issue was React's usage of keys. The shifting algorithm wasn't so much the problem as the value being passed to the component's key. Since we were simply providing the fixed alphabet as a key, React's rendering seems to have been affected by it. This was "fixed" by supplying a unique key to cycle the alphabet with a new key. Thanks for looking into this :)